# COUNTIF equivalent in dplyr summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame listing total students (Stu) and number of students per group (ID) who are taking part in an activity (Sub):

```
     ID   Stu   Sub
  (int) (int) (int)
1   101    80    NA
2   102   130    NA
3   103    10    NA
4   104   210    20
5   105   180    NA
6   106   150    NA
```

I would like to know the number of groups in size bands (>400, >200, >100, >0) who are either involved in an activity (Sub > 0), or not (Sub is.na)

```
output <- structure(list(ID = c(101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L), 
                       Stu = c(80L, 130L, 10L, 210L, 180L, 150L), 
                       Sub = c(NA,NA, NA, 20L, NA, NA)), 
                  .Names = c("ID", "Stu", "Sub"), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -6L))

temp <- output %>% 
mutate(Stu = ifelse(Stu >= 400, 400,
         ifelse(Stu >= 200, 200,
             ifelse(Stu >= 100, 100, 0
                 )))) %>%
group_by(Stu) %>%
summarise(entries = length(!is.na(Sub)),
          noentries = length(is.na(Sub)))
```

The results should be:

```
    Stu entries noentries
  (dbl)   (int)     (int)
1     0       0         2
2   100       0         3
3   200       1         0
```

But I get:

```
    Stu entries noentries
  (dbl)   (int)     (int)
1     0       2         2
2   100       3         3
3   200       1         1
```

How can I make the length function in the summarise act like a countif?

Comment: sth is wrong in your last ifelse

Comment: sorry, missed out a 0, it should be working now

Comment: `sum` is the right solution as mentioned below. Just for clarity, length returns the length of the vector it is provided. In this case, irrespective of the true/false values, the length function is returning the number of items in each group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`summarise` expects a single value, so `sum` instead of `length` does the job:

```
output %>% 
  mutate(Stu = ifelse(Stu >= 400, 400,
                      ifelse(Stu >= 200, 200,
                             ifelse(Stu >= 100, 100, 0
                             )))) %>%
  group_by(Stu) %>% 
  summarise(entries = sum(!is.na(Sub)),
            noentries = sum(is.na(Sub)))

Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

Stu entries noentries
(dbl)   (int)     (int)
1     0       0         2
2   100       0         3
3   200       1         0
```

Comment: ah yes, I forgot that is.na returns a vector of boolean, that can be summed

Answer (score 3):

Following the same idea provided by @eipi10, but cutting to the chase with `count()` instead of `group_by() %>% tally()` and showing that `tidyr::spread` can mimic `reshape2::dcast`:

```
output %>%
  count(Sub = ifelse(is.na(Sub), 'No Entries', 'Entires'),
        Stu = cut(Stu, c(0, 100, 200, 400, +Inf), labels = c(0, 100, 200, 400))) %>%
  tidyr::spread(Sub, n, fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to group by both `Stu` and `Sub`, but to do that we need to first recode the values of `Sub` and `Stu` to match the output groupings we want. We also use `cut`, instead of nested `ifelse`, to set the value breaks in `Stu`:

```
library(reshape2)

output %>% 
  group_by(Sub=ifelse(is.na(Sub), "No Entries", "Entries"),
           Stu=cut(Stu, c(0,100,200,400,Inf), labels=c(0,100,200,400))) %>%
  tally %>%
  dcast(Stu ~ Sub, fill=0)
```

> ```
>      Stu Entries No Entries
> 1      0       0          2
> 2    100       0          3
> 3    200       1          0
> ```